# composer.json / cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, musicbrainz

I want to use: https://github.com/mikealmond/MusicBrainz
Copied the lib in myapp->vendor Folder. Installed Guzzle with composer and updated composer.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use MusicBrainz\Filters\ArtistFilter;
use MusicBrainz\Filters\RecordingFilter;
use MusicBrainz\HttpAdapters\GuzzleHttpAdapter;
use MusicBrainz\MusicBrainz;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

The autoload does not work. I tried many things and don't know, what to write in the composer.json.

```
Error: Class 'MusicBrainz\MusicBrainz' not found
```

When i call:

```
$brainz = new MusicBrainz(new GuzzleHttpAdapter(new Client()));
```

I tried in composer.json

```
"require-dev": {
     "vendor/MusicBrainz": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "https://github.com/mikealmond/MusicBrainz.git"
        }
    ],
```

Then composer update...
And i get:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package src/musicbrainz could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? Why not install MusicBrainz with Composer if you're already using it for Guzzle?

Comment: CAKE_VERSION 3.2.1 // i tried to useing Composer, but it does not work and i dont find the misstake

Comment: "*it does not work*" When do people learn that this is **not** a qualified problem report? Please read the *whole* page: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: okay i edited my question and hope thats help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the linked repository page on Github. In the root folder, click on the file named `composer.json`. Search for a line with `"name"`. The text right to it is the name of this package that you have to use in Composer.

Alternatively, go to https://packagist.org and type something close to the actual name into the search field, like `musicb`. Something will be found: https://packagist.org/search/?q=musicb

In any case, you will find the package name: `mikealmond/musicbrainz`.

Now go to the command line and type: `composer require mikealmond/musicbrainz`. Composer will do the rest, including the download of Guzzle because this is declared as a dependency.

After that step, the demo code will work - or at least will not fail because of missing classes.